Install a packaged central AC for multiple rental units

https://hvacdirect.com/3-ton-13-4-seer2-aciq-ac-only-packaged-unit-paj436000k000k1.html
Hi Everyone,
We have a rental property, and I'm considering installing a packaged central AC (link above) on the roof for the summer months. The setup will include two duct pipes for each unit: one for cold air coming in and another for hot air going out to the AC unit. Assuming there is sufficient space in the attic and the electrical panel can handle an additional 35 amps of current, is this technically feasible? I believe the main challenge will be ensuring that the airflow is evenly distributed for both intake and exhaust across each unit.

Do you intend for one condenser and air handler to serve all 6 units?   If so how will the residents control the temperature in their unit?  Who or what controls the thermostat to the cooling unit?  Finally are the rental units only one room?   I'm asking to understand if this is viable.

Yeah, also this means air from 1 unit will be redistributed to ALL units, now didn't we just have a huge virus thing where sharing air was BAD? And what about food or body smells or shower humidity? This seems like a bad slumlordy idea. The modern answer is 6 split system heat pumps, many of which are very DIYable like Pioneer or Hitachi. I gather you're paying the electricity, heat pumps will be MUCH more efficient (not least, not shedding heat down all that ducting) and also provide heating cheaper than gas.  And more appealing to tenants. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFEHFsO-XSI

@ Harper, I love mini-split units. Senville are my choice. They come pre charged so you don't need an HVAC tech to install them, just a set of gauges and vacuum pump to evac the lines. I was not sure that the OP was asking what they were asking because it was so bizarre.

Bad idea, and also off topic.

I’m voting to close this question because landlord actions or rental units are not DIY as per the site desctiption

Technically it's no different than installing  a central AC system in any other building orlf that size.
Practically, I think it's the wrong answer. Tenants want easy individual control over temperature, which this will not give them. A minisplit system would, and might also be easier to install.
Note that with any kind of central system, you have to figure out how you are going to pass the operating cost along to the tenants. Neither of these options is especially amenable to charging them based on usage.

Thanks for the typo fix. Auto-incorrect is being particularly horrible today....

Good point, with one DIY mini-split e.g. Hitatchi or Pioneer per unit, it would be much easier to do submetering.
